# How to make a certain symbol disappear at a viewport break point?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the `&middot;` and both spaces disappear when the line breaks at a certain point.

For example, on a big screen it would look like this:

> © 2017 Sample Production · All Rights Reserved

On mobiles though it would break in two parts and the `&middot;` is unnessesary, so it would look like this:

> © 2017 Sample Production
>  All Rights Reserved

Is there any way to do this?

---

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aencaster/ymqa5gcg/

Comment: can you put the &middot; inside span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that dot in a `span` with a class - for example: `.dot`, and then hide it using media query with: `.dot {display: none;}`.

Simple as that. :)

Comment: That'll do, but how about avoiding media queries?

Comment: If you don't want to do it with media queries, you can always use JS - but why? Media query is much simpler.

Comment: I didn't want to use media queries because I didn't want to stick to any pixel values, although I should have.

So this would be something like that?
https://jsfiddle.net/aencaster/ymqa5gcg/

Comment: Works as it should. :)